# php pdo select multiple rows and insert to other table with LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have 2 tables `equip_copy(copyID, equipment_id)` and insert it to table

```
mre_copy (mreID,copyID,equipment_id)
```

I have tried this Select query but doesnt move. Please anyone can help me?

```
$display = $con->query("SELECT copyID,equipmentID
                         FROM equip_copy
                         WHERE equipmentID= :eid
                         ORDER BY copyID DESC 
                         LIMIT :elimit");

$display->execute(array("eid" => $id, "elimit"=>$request));

foreach($display as $row){

        $newCID = $row['copyID']; 
        $newEID = $row['equipmentID'];

        $sql_table = "INSERT INTO mre_copy(mreID,equipmentID,copyID) values(?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql_table);
        $stmt->execute(array($mreID,$newEID,$newCID));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`.  I think this is what you want to do

```
INSERT INTO mre_copy (mreID, equipmentID, copyID) 
    SELECT :mreID, copyID, equipmentID
    FROM equip_copy
    WHERE equipmentID = :eid
    ORDER BY copyID DESC 
    LIMIT :elimit;
```

I'm not sure where `mreID` comes from.  If it is auto-incremented, then just leave it out of the `INSERT` altogether.

Comment: i cant select all data using while.. what is the right syntax for that